# CSS3Pie Shadow not working

Tags: css, css3pie

I have such css

```
padding: 30px 15px 15px 15px;
background-color: #fff;
border-left: solid 1px #86b0ca; 
border-right: solid 1px #86b0ca;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 20px 20px -20px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 20px 20px -20px #000000;
box-shadow:inset 0px 20px 20px -20px #000000;
font-size: 1em;
behavior: url("PIE.htc");
```

but i couldn't get shadow working in ie. I get working rounded corners in another styles, but shadows seams to be a bit problem.

How could i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#box-shadow):

> PIE does not currently support the 'inset' keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: relative;` or `zoom: 1;`, or both? The question is a little vague so I can't give you much more help. What element is it on?

Comment: Tried to add both, no way, it is on div.